# how to use css align control one row

Tags: c#, css

I use visual studio 2010 with framework2.0

I design a page use c# ,now ,just called A.aspx.

the page have a table to layout, 
like

```
     <table> <tr>
        <td>
        Name
        </td>
        <td>
        <asp:TextBox .../>
        <div id="div1" style="vertical-align: bottom;">
         <img.. />
            </div>
        <div><img ../></div>
        <asp:Label .../>
        <asp:Label .../>
        </td>

        </tr>
       </table>
```

Now ,I want to let **second**`<td></td>` layout one row. how to set up?

**I try `<td style ="float:left">` but not worked,it always show two row.**

can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First understand your layout, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pCVyB/) is an example with borders

If you want to float elements try a layout using div and css

A layout with tables is very hard to work with and nobody is doing it anymore. You can use tables for specific situation only if you like but most of the time try to use div layout and the other elements to organize content.

**HTML**

```
<table class="borde">
<tr class="borde">
<td class="borde">
Name
</td>
<td class="borde">
fffff
<div class="divRojo"></div>
fffff 
</td>

</tr>

</table>
```

**CSS**

```
 .borde { border:1px solid black; }

 .divRojo { border:1px solid red; }
```

With one more row and the div

```
<table class="borde">
<tr class="borde">
<td class="borde">
Name
</td>
<td class="borde">
fffff
<div class="divRojo"></div>
fffff 
</td>

</tr>

<tr>
   <td colspan="2">
   <div>Content in one column in a new row</div>
   </td>
</tr>


</table>
```

Comment: Yes,table is not a good choice to layout page, but I do a enhancement project, it's old. haha. your css just show border, not solve how to layout one row

Comment: Yes is just to understand the content. If you wan a new row add another tr and if you want to consolidate a new row with only one column use colspan=2 in the td. Is that what you want?

Comment: here ,I just only have two <td> tags. cannot add more .

Comment: I have two <td></td> ,the first<td>Name<td/>, the second <td><label> <textbox><div> </td>   ,the first <td> cannot lack of. so cannot use colspan =2 in one tr

Comment: Where are the tr tags and table?

Answer (score 2):

You want your second `<td>` in one row?  So, create another `<tr>`?

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Name
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <textarea></textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**http://jsbin.com/uJenUVOx/1/edit**

Comment: Right.  So what do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

I have fix this question ,the second `<td>` use `<table>` then can solve that question.